# Is there any way to apply a Terraform property only after an update?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy an Azure Key Vault using Terraform and to populate it with a key - I am creating a `azurerm_key_vault` and a `azurerm_key_vault_key`. I would like to disable public access to the Key Vault completely, but setting `public_network_access_enabled` to false means that the key cannot be deployed anymore, as I get a 403 error due to the public access being disabled.

Is there any way I can set the `public_network_access_enabled` property only on updates, or after the key is created?

Comment: If allowed to achieve this w/o terraform then you can create a Azure Policy that enforces the public_network_access_enabled property to be set to false on your Azure Key Vault.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can set the `public_network_access_enabled` property only on updates, or after the key is created?

There is a workaround to set the `public_network_access_enabled` property only after the key is created in the `Key Vault` using a `null_resource` block with a `local-exec` provisioned using `Terraform`.

**Terraform:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    key_vault {
      purge_soft_deleted_keys_on_destroy = true
      recover_soft_deleted_keys          = true
    }
  }
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "<existing resource_group>" {
  name = "<resource_group>"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "venkatkeyvault" {
  name                       = "venkat-keyvault-test"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.<existing resource_group>.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.<existing resource_group>.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "premium"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Update",
      "GetRotationPolicy",
      "SetRotationPolicy",
      "List"
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Set",
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "generated" {
  name         = "sample-key"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.venkatkeyvault.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]

  rotation_policy {
    automatic {
      time_before_expiry = "P30D"
    }

    expire_after         = "P90D"
    notify_before_expiry = "P29D"
  }
}
resource "null_resource" "powershell" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
    az keyvault update --name "venkat-keyvault-test" --resource-group "<existing resource_group>  --public-network-access "Disabled"
    EOT
  }
}
```

Terraform apply:

[image]

Once ran the above terraform code `Key vault` **public access** has been disabled.

[image]

When you run the above `Terraform` code, it will create a `Key Vault` with a key inside the `Key Vault`. After that, it will update the `Key Vault's` public network access to **'Disabled'** using the `Azure CLI` command provided in the `null_resource` block defined with a `local-exec` provisioner

Reference:  [az keyvault update](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault)